# how to display a rendered latex output on sage math cloud

Tags: latex, sympy, tex, sage

Is there a way to display a rendered LaTex output on the Sage Math cloud? I am looking for something along the lines of the sympy live shell, but with functionality for plotting.

Comment: Although this looks an interesting question it doesn't appear to be about programming — which is what SO is for. If it is about programming you should show what you've tried to do on Sage Math that didn't lead to success, so that others can suggest possibilities.

Comment: The way you use Sage is by writing a program of sorts to do mathematical calculations. I am just wondering if there is a way to output in rendered latex. The command latex() will output raw LaTex code

Comment: your question is weird, because for me rendered latex output is usually a PDF. I suggest you to ask at the mailing list groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-cloud and give a concrete example with an explanation.

Comment: @HaraldSchilly a good example is the sympy live shell over at http://live.sympy.org/

Comment: Still trying to understand: (1) 'looking for something along the lines of the sympy live shell,  but with functionality for plotting': Apparently the live shell doesn't do plots but if you run sympy in a REPL such as PythonWin you can do live plotting. Would that suit? (2) As you likely know, sympy can also give you the raw Latex of an expression. You can display and save the image of one of those in the Chrome browser using, for instance, the Daum Equation Editor. This works for the Sage Math result too, of course.